# Distribution of balls in leftmost bin

Tags: probability

> There are $M$ bins a row and $n$ balls. If each of these balls is placed independently into one of the bins at random, then what is the distribution of the balls in the bin to the left?

Based on my understanding, the balls are indistinguishable, while the bins are distinguishable (since we can tell one of the bins is the left-most bin in the line.), so I think the probability of a ball in one of these bins is given by $M-1\choose{n-1}$, but I'm not sure. I don't think that the left most bin would have a different probability than any other bin either.

Comment: Let $\alpha$ be

Comment: Your solution is wrong in first place because n is not necessarely smaller than M. Let $\alpha=\frac {1}{M}$. Then the probability of one ball falling in the first bin is $\alpha $. If I throw two balls I have probability $\alpha^2$ of finding both in the firs bin, $2\alpha (1-\alpha)$ of finding only one ball in the first bin and $(1-\alpha)^$ of none falling in the first bin. Can you see where this is going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most practical examples, everything is distinguishable if you want to use an equiprobable counting method.  In this case for example you can put the balls in one-by-one, so you have a natural order

Each ball either goes into the leftmost bin or into one of the other bins, so you can model the distribution of balls in the leftmost bin with the binomial distribution: $\displaystyle P(i) = {n \choose i}\left( \frac{1}{M}\right)^i\left(\frac{M-1}{M}\right)^{n-i}$

Each of the other bins has the same marginal distribution, though they are not independent

Comment: If I wanted the expected value of the number of empty boxes, would it just be $\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{i=1}^n iP(X=i)= i {n \choose i}\left( \frac{1}{M}\right)^i\left(\frac{M-1}{M}\right)^{M-i}$?

Comment: The first box has probability $\left(\frac{M-1}{M}\right)^{n}$ of being empty, and similarly for each other box. You can use linearity of expectation to say the expected number of empty boxes is  $M\left(\frac{M-1}{M}\right)^{n}$ or equivalently $\frac{(M-1)^{n-1}}{M^n}$